# ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.error during deploying on tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

my code is working fine if i right click on server and run as run on server , but when i try to deploy it on tomcat and try to  run it it is giving me below error

log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.Controller = INFO,error,stdout
log4j.logger.Client = INFO,error,stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

error:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.error
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "error".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.error
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "error".
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

pom.xml :

```
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Is this file in your classpath

Comment: If you showed the complete log4j.properties file, there is indeed no appender `error`defined.

Comment: yeah i have shown my complete log file but i didnt get what you want to say can you explain

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
log4j.logger.Controller = INFO,error,stdout
log4j.logger.Client = INFO,error,stdout
```

You can only specify one logger level as the first argument (in this case INFO), and then the next two arguments are going to be considered the appender names to use for that logger (in this case error and stdout). Because no appender named error exists, you are getting the errors you've reported.

Check this out (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) that shows an example of assigning a logger to two different appenders that looks a lot like your code. Hopefully this will help explain why log4j is looking for an appender named error in your application.

> Here is another configuration file that uses multiple appenders.
>
> log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R
>
> log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>
> log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
>
> log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.R.File=example.log
>
> log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
>
> log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n