# Log4j logs are not printing with Wildfly10

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, wildfly, wildfly-10

Log4j logs are not printing when I deploy my war on Wildfly10.1.0.Final. However its working fine with Tomcat.

I found on web that Wildfly uses log4j so i excluded log4j in jboss-deployment-structure.xml as below to avaoid dependency conflicts but no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <!-- for top deployment, e.g. ear -->
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name='org.slf4j.impl' />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc" />
            <module name="peslib" />
             
        </exclusions>
         
    </deployment>

    <!-- for sub deployment, e.g. war. sub-deployment is required when ear contains one or more wars -->
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Below is my log4.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,file,Stdout

log4j.logger.com.persivia.ptf=INFO

log4j.appender.Stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.Stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}] [%p] %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/Logs/ptf-patient-service.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}] [%p] %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Below is my pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Servlet Spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4jVersion}</version>
             <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Swagger UI dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- portal imports end -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Mockito -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
              <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
              <version>2.28.2</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
```

And below is error logs I am getting when I deploy the war.

```
19:04:01,579 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
19:04:01,579 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by
19:04:01,581 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:ERROR [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ptf-patient-service.war:main" from Service Module Loader] whereas object of type
19:04:01,584 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" was loaded by [ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main" from local module loader @33e5ccce (finder: local module finder @5a42bbf4 (roots: C:\wildfly\modules,C:\wildfly\modules\system\layers\base))].
19:04:01,585 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "file".
19:04:01,586 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
19:04:01,586 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by
19:04:01,587 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:ERROR [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ptf-patient-service.war:main" from Service Module Loader] whereas object of type
19:04:01,587 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" was loaded by [ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main" from local module loader @33e5ccce (finder: local module finder @5a42bbf4 (roots: C:\wildfly\modules,C:\wildfly\modules\system\layers\base))].
19:04:01,588 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "Stdout".
```

I am trying to run through standalone-full-ha.xml

Comment: Please see the answer in this post and see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760493/error-could-not-find-value-for-key-log4j-appender-error-during-deploying-on-tomc

Comment: You do not want to remove the slf4j exclusions because you are providing slf4j. Where is your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` located? It looks like the servers version of log4j is not being excluded. You also don't have log4j 1.x defined, in your POM you've got log4j2 which means you also have the wrong slf4j binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following lines from your exclusions list:

```
 <module name="org.slf4j" />
 <module name='org.slf4j.impl' />
```

Comment: I removed the above mentioned lines but that didn't solved the problem.